# How to save thumbnail image while maintaining the correct aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, bitmap, aspect-ratio

I am developing a website using ASP.net. In there users can upload images. When I am saving images I am saveing a small version ( Thumbnail ) image.
To do that I use this code

```
public void SaveThumbnailImage(Stream sourcePath, int width, int height, string imageFileName)
{
    using (var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(sourcePath))
    {
        //a holder for the result
        Bitmap result = new Bitmap(width, height);

        //set the resolutions the same to avoid cropping due to resolution differences
        result.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

        //use a graphics object to draw the resized image into the bitmap
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(result))
        {
            //set the resize quality modes to high quality
            graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            //draw the image into the target bitmap
            graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, result.Width, result.Height);
        }

        thumbnailfullImagePath = string.Format("/Images/thumbnail/{0}", imageFileName);
        result.Save(Server.MapPath(thumbnailfullImagePath), image.RawFormat);
    }
}
```

height is :105
width is 150

Above cord working fine for landscape type photos. But If I upload a portrait photos its not maintain its correct resolotuions. So how to optimize above code to save the thumbnail while keeping its original width to height ratio?

Answer (score 1):

You can simple reduce the width and height of image by some factor. Here is the example code where i used factor 10.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

public partial class thumbnail : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("images/send.png"));

        int factor = 10;
        int new_width = image.Width / factor;
        int new_height = image.Height / factor;

        System.Drawing.Image thumbnail = image.GetThumbnailImage(new_width,
            new_height, null, IntPtr.Zero);

        thumbnail.Save(Server.MapPath("images/send_thumbnail.png"));
    }
}
```